# How to get the missing ids present list B but present in list A excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 2 lists, List-A and List-B which are having ids more than 450000. I want to find the missing ids in list-B but present in list-A in excel.

Comment: Use match() or vlookup()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try 2 formulas:

```
VLOOKUP: =VLOOKUP(List-A!A2;List-B!$A$2:$A$5;1;FALSE)
```

Drag down/Copy and paste the formula in the column next to your ID column in List-A.  If you receive a #N/A after you drag down the formula, then you know that the ID number is in List-A but not in List-B.

```
INDEX-MATCH: =INDEX(List-B!$A$2:$A$5;MATCH(List-A!A2;List-B!$A$2:$A$5;0))
```

Again the same concept, if you receive a #N/A after you drag down the formula, then you know that the ID number is in List-A but not in List-B.